# Minecraft Modding - Item Lore not showing

Tags: minecraft

Any help on this? It does not work. Someone told me to create an instance of the GymDbellItem class, i do not know how to do it.. help?

GymDbellItem.java

```
package com.bagasmc.gym.items;

import java.util.List;

import com.bagasmc.gym.handlers.CreativeTabHandler;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.registry.GameRegistry;

public class GymDbellItem extends Item {

    public static ItemBase gymDumbbell;
    public static ItemStack dumBell;

     public static void init() {
     gymDumbbell = register(new ItemBase("dumbBell").setCreativeTab(CreativeTabHandler.tabBlocks));
     }

     @Override
     public void addInformation(ItemStack stack, EntityPlayer player, List list, boolean check) {
      list.add("     STAMINA     ");
      list.add("3 kilos   6.6 lbs");

     }

    private static <T extends Item> T register(T item) {
        GameRegistry.register(item);

        if(item instanceof ItemModelProvider) {
            ((ItemModelProvider)item).registerItemModel(item);
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

It does not show the lore :(

Answer (score 0):

The `Item` class you've shown is `GymDbellItem`, but in your `init` method, you're instantiating an `ItemBase`, not a `GymDbellItem`. Since the lore is added from the `GymDbellItem.addInformation` method, it will never be called when you're using `ItemBase`.

In your `init` method, change the `new ItemBase` constructor to `new GymDbellItem`.

Additionally, you may want to change your `GymDbellItem` to extend your `ItemBase` class instead of Minecraft's `Item` class, so it works with the rest of your code.